# How to make unknown number of divs fill all the remaining space equally?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to earn the next result:

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}
.a{
  background-color: red;
}
.b{
  background-color: blue;
}
.right > *{
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<p>Problem</p>
<div class="wrong container">
  <div class="a">text</div>
  <div class="b">text</div>
</div>
<p>Expected</p>
<div class="right container">
  <div class="a">text</div>
  <div class="b">text</div>
</div>
```

If we know the number of elements inside the container, it's obvious that we can set the childs width manually. But what if we don't know the number of childs, but we want them to fill all the parent's available width in the way that all of them are equal wide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just added `flex: 1` to every div element.

Check out this article: [a complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

TLDR:

> This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis
>   combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis)
>   are optional. Default is 0 1 auto.

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
}
.item{
  flex: 1;
}
.a{
  background-color: red;
}
.b{
  background-color: blue;
}
.right > *{
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<p>Problem</p>
<div class="wrong container">
  <div class="a">text</div>
  <div class="b">text</div>
</div>
<p>Expected</p>
<div class="right container">
  <div class="a item">text</div>
  <div class="b item">text</div>
  <div class="C item">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use flex.

```
  .container{
  width: 100vw;
 height: 40vh;
 display: flex;
background-color: gray;
display:flex
   }
  .container > div{
flex-grow: 1;
 }
```

```css
.container{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 40vh;
  display: flex;
  background-color: gray;
  display:flex
}
.container > div{
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.a{
  background-color: red;
}
.b{
  background-color: blue;
}
.right > *{
  width: 50%
}
```

```html
<p>Problem</p>
<div class="wrong container">
  <div class="a">text</div>
  <div class="b">text</div>
</div>
<p>Expected</p>
<div class="right container">
  <div class="a">text</div>
  <div class="b">text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Add this to your CSS. Of course, this is a rough solution. A better approach will be to create a class instead of applying this to all divs in the page.